# UEFI boot options doesn't appear in efibootmgr

Tags: boot, arch-linux, uefi

Hello everyone, I'm new here treat me well ;)

I want to change the boot order with `efibootmgr` but in the boot order appears options that I can't select.

```
# efibootmgr
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0004,2003,2001,2002
Boot0001* UEFI: Network Card 
Boot0002* UEFI: Network Card 
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM
Boot2003* EFI Network
```

I didn't try to change that BootOrder with the current options because I suspect that Arch is 0000 or 0004 and the option of `efibootmgr -A XXXX` doesn't seem to work.

What can I do? Thank you every1.

Comment: Looks more like corrupted NVRAM data to me, seeing how 0000 is repeated a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's being a while since I've worked with UEFI but I'll give it a try answering this.

Depending on your hardware implementation some boards are trying to find "specific" EFI kernels and boot them up before, reaching the BootOrder.

So even if you have a specific BootOrder, some boards will try to find a windows EFI kernel or (in my case) a redhat EFI grub kernel (even that I am using archlinux !!!) and that is a EFI entry to your bios setup and overwrites the BootOrder.

That's said, here is my efibootmgr to get an idea:

```
# efibootmgr 
BootCurrent: 000A
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006,000A,0008,0009,0007
Boot0000  Setup
Boot0001  Boot Menu
Boot0002* Removable Drive
Boot0003* Hard Drive
Boot0004* USB Storage Device
Boot0005* CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive
Boot0006* Network
Boot0007* Network Boot
Boot0008  Diagnostics
Boot0009  Change boot mode setting
Boot000A* archlinux
```

on a Dell XPS L322X that boots up directly to 000A !!

```
# file EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi: PE32+ executable x86-64, for MS Windows
# file EFI/redhat/grub.efi 
EFI/redhat/grub.efi: PE32+ executable (EFI application) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
```

Hope that helped a little.